# Is there a better way to transfer my "Google Map" data over ethernet from H.264?

Tags: android, google-maps, embedded, ethernet, data-transfer

I have a beginning of some kind of embedded project. I have two embedded systems/devices and they will connect together with the **ethernet** feature/cable. I will receive **Google Maps data in one of them and I want to show this data also on the other device**. I want to **transfer map data** and think about the ways of it. I get the suggestion of the transfer **H.264 format** (which is Advanced Video Coding) but I am not quite sure it will be the optimal solution for this problem because H.264 is generally used in youtube videos, HDTVs, etc... I think about the send only **x,y,z coordinates to other devices** but it will come with the **problem with implementing Google Maps to the other device**. So I want to ask is there a better way or better format for transferring my map data from one device to another device via ethernet.